# 403 error after adding javascript to masterpage for sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007, http-status-code-403

I am attempting to add highslide-with-html.js from http://highslide.com/ to my masterpage. I am receiving a 403 forbidden error when I use the provided masterpage.

I have placed it in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033. Test javascript files  such as pirate.js
which consists solely of `alert("Arr!");` have loaded from the same directory. I have  provided the code for the masterpage. When I do not reference the problem javascript file there is no 403 error.

```
<%@ Master language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="DesignModeConsole" src="~/_controltemplates/DesignModeConsole.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingVariations" TagName="VariationsLabelMenu" src="~/_controltemplates/VariationsLabelMenu.ascx" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingConsole" TagName="Console" src="~/_controltemplates/PublishingConsole.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingSiteAction" TagName="SiteActionMenu" src="~/_controltemplates/PublishingActionMenu.ascx" %>
<html dir="<%$Resources:wss, multipages_direction_dir_value %>" runat="server" __expr-val-dir="ltr">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server" __designer:Preview="" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='InDesign' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl00' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>
    <title id="onetidTitle">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/>
    </title>
    <Sharepoint:CssLink runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/Style%20Library/en-US/Core%20Styles/Band.css&quot;/&gt;
&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/Style%20Library/en-US/Core%20Styles/controls.css&quot;/&gt;
&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/Style%20Library/zz1_blue.css&quot;/&gt;
&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/_layouts/1033/styles/core.css&quot;/&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='InDesign' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl01' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>
    <!--Styles used for positioning, font and spacing definitions-->
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/Band.css%>" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/Style%20Library/en-US/Core%20Styles/Band.css&quot;/&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='Name' Bound='True' T='SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/Band.css' /&gt;&lt;P N='InDesign' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl02' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/controls.css %>" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/Style%20Library/en-US/Core%20Styles/controls.css&quot;/&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='Name' Bound='True' T='SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/controls.css' /&gt;&lt;P N='InDesign' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl03' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/zz1_blue.css%>" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/Style%20Library/zz1_blue.css&quot;/&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='Name' Bound='True' T='SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/zz1_blue.css' /&gt;&lt;P N='InDesign' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl04' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="init.js" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;script src=&quot;/_layouts/1033/init.js?rev=VhAxGc3rkK79RM90tibDzw%3D%3D&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='Name' T='init.js' /&gt;&lt;P N='InDesign' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl05' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="highslide-with-html.js" runat="server" __designer:Error="Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\layouts\1033\highslide-with-html.js' is denied."/>
    <!--Placeholder for additional overrides-->
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server"/>
</head>
<body class="body" onload="javascript:_spBodyOnLoadWrapper();">
    <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server"/>
    <form runat="server" onsubmit="return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="master">
        <tr>
            <td height="100%" class="shadowLeft">
                <div class="spacer">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="masterContent">
                                <tr style="height:0px"><td>
                                    <wssuc:DesignModeConsole id="IdDesignModeConsole" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;span __designer:NonVisual=&quot;true&quot;&gt;[ DesignModeConsoleContainer &quot;DesignModeContainer&quot; ]&lt;/span&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ID' ID='1' T='IdDesignModeConsole' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' R='0' /&gt;"/></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="authoringRegion">
                             <span class="siteActionMenu">
                                <PublishingSiteAction:SiteActionMenu runat="server" __designer:Preview="
&lt;!-- Begin Action Menu Markup --&gt;
&lt;table height=100% class=&quot;ms-siteaction&quot; cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;
    &lt;tr&gt;
                       &lt;td class=&quot;ms-siteactionsmenu&quot; id=&quot;siteactiontd&quot;&gt;


                        &lt;span style=&quot;display:none&quot;&gt;&lt;menu type='ServerMenu' id=&quot;zz1_SiteActionsMenuMain&quot; largeIconMode=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;ie:menuitem id=&quot;zz2_MenuItem_Create&quot; type=&quot;option&quot; iconSrc=&quot;/_layouts/images/Actionscreate.gif&quot; onMenuClick=&quot;window.location = '/_layouts/create.aspx';&quot; menuGroupId=&quot;100&quot;&gt;&lt;/ie:menuitem&gt;&lt;ie:menuitem id=&quot;zz3_MenuItem_Settings&quot; type=&quot;option&quot; iconSrc=&quot;/_layouts/images/ActionsSettings.gif&quot; onMenuClick=&quot;window.location = '/_layouts/settings.aspx';&quot; menuGroupId=&quot;100&quot;&gt;&lt;/ie:menuitem&gt;&lt;/menu&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span title=&quot;Open Menu&quot;&gt;&lt;div  id=&quot;zz4_SiteActionsMenu_t&quot; class=&quot;&quot; onmouseover=&quot;MMU_PopMenuIfShowing(this);MMU_EcbTableMouseOverOut(this, true)&quot; hoverActive=&quot;ms-siteactionsmenuhover&quot; hoverInactive=&quot;&quot; onclick=&quot; MMU_Open(byid(''), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz4_SiteActionsMenu'),event,false, null, 0);&quot; foa=&quot;MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz4_SiteActionsMenu')&quot; oncontextmenu=&quot;this.click(); return false;&quot; nowrap=&quot;nowrap&quot;&gt;&lt;a id=&quot;zz4_SiteActionsMenu&quot; accesskey=&quot;/&quot; href=&quot;#&quot; onclick=&quot;javascript:return false;&quot; style=&quot;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap;&quot; onfocus=&quot;MMU_EcbLinkOnFocusBlur(byid(''), this, true);&quot; onkeydown=&quot;MMU_EcbLinkOnKeyDown(byid(''), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz4_SiteActionsMenu'), event);&quot; onclick=&quot; MMU_Open(byid(''), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz4_SiteActionsMenu'),event,false, null, 0);&quot; oncontextmenu=&quot;this.click(); return false;&quot; menuTokenValues=&quot;MENUCLIENTID=zz4_SiteActionsMenu,TEMPLATECLIENTID=zz1_SiteActionsMenuMain&quot; serverclientid=&quot;zz4_SiteActionsMenu&quot;&gt;Site Actions&lt;img src=&quot;/_layouts/images/blank.gif&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window).&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img align=&quot;absbottom&quot; src=&quot;/_layouts/images/whitearrow.gif&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;
&lt;!-- End Action Menu Markup --&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='TemplateControl' R='0' /&gt;"/>
                            </span>
                        <div class="sharepointLogin">
                        <!--Authentication for Authors only-->
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ms-globallinks">
                                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink1" Scope="Farm" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;span style='padding-left:3px'&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;a id=&quot;ctl00_ctl09_hlMySite&quot; href=&quot;http://litwaredemo:80/MySite/_layouts/MySite.aspx&quot;&gt;My Site&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;span style='padding-left:4px;padding-right:3px'&gt;|&lt;/span&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ControlId' T='GlobalSiteLink1' /&gt;&lt;P N='Scope' T='Farm' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl08' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/></td>
                                    <td class="ms-globallinks">
                                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" Scope="Farm" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;span id=&quot;ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenu&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;display:none&quot;&gt;&lt;menu type='ServerMenu' id=&quot;ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenuTemplate&quot; largeIconMode=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;/menu&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span title=&quot;Open Menu&quot;&gt;&lt;span  id=&quot;ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenu_t&quot; class=&quot;ms-SPLink ms-hovercellinactive&quot; onmouseover=&quot;MMU_PopMenuIfShowing(this);MMU_EcbTableMouseOverOut(this, true)&quot; hoverActive=&quot;ms-SPLink ms-hovercellactive&quot; hoverInactive=&quot;ms-SPLink ms-hovercellinactive&quot; onclick=&quot;javascript:FetchCallbackMenuItems(&amp;#39;ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenuTemplate&amp;#39;); MMU_Open(byid('ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenuTemplate'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenu'),event,true, null, 0);&quot; foa=&quot;MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenu')&quot; oncontextmenu=&quot;this.click(); return false;&quot; nowrap=&quot;nowrap&quot;&gt;&lt;a id=&quot;ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenu&quot; accesskey=&quot;M&quot; href=&quot;#&quot; onclick=&quot;javascript:return false;&quot; style=&quot;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap;&quot; onfocus=&quot;MMU_EcbLinkOnFocusBlur(byid('ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenuTemplate'), this, true);&quot; onkeydown=&quot;MMU_EcbLinkOnKeyDown(byid('ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenuTemplate'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenu'), event);&quot; onclick=&quot;javascript:FetchCallbackMenuItems(&amp;#39;ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenuTemplate&amp;#39;); MMU_Open(byid('ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenuTemplate'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenu'),event,true, null, 0);&quot; oncontextmenu=&quot;this.click(); return false;&quot; menuTokenValues=&quot;MENUCLIENTID=ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenu,TEMPLATECLIENTID=ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenuTemplate&quot; serverclientid=&quot;ctl00_ctl11_MyLinksMenuMenu&quot;&gt;My Links&lt;img src=&quot;/_layouts/images/blank.gif&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window).&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img align=&quot;absbottom&quot; src=&quot;/_layouts/images/menudark.gif&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;|" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ControlId' T='GlobalSiteLink2' /&gt;&lt;P N='Scope' T='Farm' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl10' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/></td>
                                    <td class="ms-globallinks">
                                    <wssuc:Welcome id="explitLogout" runat="server" __designer:Preview="

    &lt;span style=&quot;display:none&quot;&gt;&lt;menu type='ServerMenu' id=&quot;zz5_ID_PersonalActionMenu&quot; largeIconMode=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;ie:menuitem id=&quot;zz6_ID_PersonalInformation&quot; type=&quot;option&quot; iconSrc=&quot;/_layouts/images/menuprofile.gif&quot; onMenuClick=&quot;javascript:GoToPage('\u002f_layouts\u002fuserdisp.aspx?Force=True\u0026ID=' + _spUserId);return false;&quot; menuGroupId=&quot;100&quot;&gt;&lt;/ie:menuitem&gt;&lt;ie:menuitem id=&quot;zz7_ID_LoginAsDifferentUser&quot; type=&quot;option&quot; onMenuClick=&quot;javascript:LoginAsAnother('\u002f_layouts\u002fAccessDenied.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true', 0)&quot; menuGroupId=&quot;200&quot;&gt;&lt;/ie:menuitem&gt;&lt;ie:menuitem id=&quot;zz8_ID_RequestAccess&quot; type=&quot;option&quot; onMenuClick=&quot;window.location = '/_layouts/reqacc.aspx?type=list&amp;amp;name=%7B36F0105B%2D0F8E%2D4A22%2DBE90%2D716A51E97B5D%7D';&quot; menuGroupId=&quot;200&quot;&gt;&lt;/ie:menuitem&gt;&lt;ie:menuitem id=&quot;zz9_ID_Logout&quot; type=&quot;option&quot; onMenuClick=&quot;window.location = '/_layouts/SignOut.aspx';&quot; menuGroupId=&quot;200&quot;&gt;&lt;/ie:menuitem&gt;&lt;/menu&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span title=&quot;Open Menu&quot;&gt;&lt;div  id=&quot;zz10_Menu_t&quot; class=&quot;ms-SPLink ms-SpLinkButtonInActive&quot; onmouseover=&quot;MMU_PopMenuIfShowing(this);MMU_EcbTableMouseOverOut(this, true)&quot; hoverActive=&quot;ms-SPLink ms-SpLinkButtonActive&quot; hoverInactive=&quot;ms-SPLink ms-SpLinkButtonInActive&quot; onclick=&quot; MMU_Open(byid(''), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz10_Menu'),event,false, null, 0);&quot; foa=&quot;MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz10_Menu')&quot; oncontextmenu=&quot;this.click(); return false;&quot; nowrap=&quot;nowrap&quot;&gt;&lt;a id=&quot;zz10_Menu&quot; accesskey=&quot;L&quot; href=&quot;#&quot; onclick=&quot;javascript:return false;&quot; style=&quot;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap;&quot; onfocus=&quot;MMU_EcbLinkOnFocusBlur(byid(''), this, true);&quot; onkeydown=&quot;MMU_EcbLinkOnKeyDown(byid(''), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz10_Menu'), event);&quot; onclick=&quot; MMU_Open(byid(''), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz10_Menu'),event,false, null, 0);&quot; oncontextmenu=&quot;this.click(); return false;&quot; menuTokenValues=&quot;MENUCLIENTID=zz10_Menu,TEMPLATECLIENTID=zz5_ID_PersonalActionMenu&quot; serverclientid=&quot;zz10_Menu&quot;&gt;Welcome LitwareInc Administrator&lt;img src=&quot;/_layouts/images/blank.gif&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window).&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img align=&quot;absbottom&quot; src=&quot;/_layouts/images/menudark.gif&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; language=&quot;javascript&quot;&gt;var _spUserId=1;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;a id=&quot;explitLogout_ExplicitLogin&quot; Href=&quot;_controltemplates/http://litwaredemo/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx&quot; style=&quot;display:none&quot;&gt;Sign In&lt;/a&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ID' ID='1' T='explitLogout' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' R='0' /&gt;"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="console">
                            <PublishingConsole:Console runat="server" __designer:Preview="
&lt;!-- Console --&gt;
&lt;span id=&quot;ctl00_publishingContext1&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;


&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; language=&quot;javascript&quot;&gt;if (document.getElementById('mpdmconsole')) { ShowConsoleBlockPaddingWithOverhang('mpLeftBackPadding', 'mpRightBackPadding', 'masterPageLeftOverhang', 'masterPageRightOverhang'); } &lt;/script&gt;

&lt;!-- Console --&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='TemplateControl' R='0' /&gt;"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" >
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" class="topArea">
                                    <SharePoint:AspMenu ID="logoLinkId" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSourceRoot" StaticDisplayLevels="1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
                                    AccessKey="1" CssClass="logo" __designer:Preview="&lt;table id=&quot;zz12_logoLinkId&quot; class=&quot;logo&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;&gt;
    &lt;tr id=&quot;zz12_logoLinkIdn0&quot;&gt;
        &lt;td&gt;&lt;table cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td style=&quot;white-space:nowrap;width:100%;&quot;&gt;&lt;a Href=&quot;/Pages/Default.aspx&quot; accesskey=&quot;1&quot; style=&quot;text-decoration:none;&quot;&gt;Home&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ID' T='logoLinkId' /&gt;&lt;P N='MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels' T='0' /&gt;&lt;P N='DataSourceID' T='SiteMapDataSourceRoot' /&gt;&lt;P N='AccessKey' T='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='ControlStyle'&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' ID='1' T='logo' /&gt;&lt;P N='Font' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='IsEmpty' T='False' /&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' R='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='Font' R='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='3' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='4' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;" __designer:Templates="&lt;Group Name=&quot;Item Templates&quot;&gt;&lt;Template Name=&quot;StaticItemTemplate&quot; Flags=&quot;D&quot; Content=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;Template Name=&quot;DynamicItemTemplate&quot; Flags=&quot;D&quot; Content=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Group&gt;"/>
                                    <PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSourceRoot" Runat="server"
                                        SiteMapProvider="CombinedNavSiteMapProvider" EnableViewState="true"
                                        StartFromCurrentNode="true" StartingNodeOffset="0" ShowStartingNode="true" __designer:Preview="&lt;table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 style=&quot;font:messagebox;color:buttontext;background-color:buttonface;border: solid 1px;border-top-color:buttonhighlight;border-left-color:buttonhighlight;border-bottom-color:buttonshadow;border-right-color:buttonshadow&quot;&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td nowrap&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:bold&quot;&gt;PortalSiteMapDataSource&lt;/span&gt; - SiteMapDataSourceRoot&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;/table&gt;" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ID' T='SiteMapDataSourceRoot' /&gt;&lt;P N='SiteMapProvider' T='CombinedNavSiteMapProvider' /&gt;&lt;P N='StartFromCurrentNode' T='True' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>
                                <div class="topLinkBar">
                                    <div class="topLink">
                                    <PublishingVariations:VariationsLabelMenu id="labelmenu1" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;span __designer:NonVisual=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 style=&quot;font:messagebox;color:buttontext;background-color:buttonface;border: solid 1px;border-top-color:buttonhighlight;border-left-color:buttonhighlight;border-bottom-color:buttonshadow;border-right-color:buttonshadow&quot;&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td nowrap&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:bold&quot;&gt;VariationDataSource&lt;/span&gt; - LabelMenuDataSource&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;/table&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ID' ID='1' T='labelmenu1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' R='0' /&gt;"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr class="topNavContainer">
                            <td class="topNavRoundLeft">
                                <div class="glassSpacerLeft" />
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" width="100%">
                                <SharePoint:AspMenu ID="GlobalNav" Runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
                                Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
                                StaticSubMenuIndent="0" DynamicHorizontalOffset="0" DynamicVerticalOffset="-8"
                                StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" ItemWrap="false" SkipLinkText="<%$Resources:cms,masterpages_skiplinktext%>" CssClass="topNav" __designer:Preview="&lt;table id=&quot;zz13_GlobalNav&quot; class=&quot;topNav&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;&gt;
    &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td title=&quot;Document Center site&quot; id=&quot;zz13_GlobalNavn0&quot;&gt;&lt;table class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td style=&quot;white-space:nowrap;&quot;&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; Href=&quot;/Docs&quot; style=&quot;text-decoration:none;border-style:none;&quot;&gt;Document Center&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td title=&quot;Company News Home&quot; id=&quot;zz13_GlobalNavn1&quot;&gt;&lt;table class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td style=&quot;white-space:nowrap;&quot;&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; Href=&quot;/News/Pages/Default.aspx&quot; style=&quot;text-decoration:none;border-style:none;&quot;&gt;News&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td title=&quot;Report Center&quot; id=&quot;zz13_GlobalNavn2&quot;&gt;&lt;table class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td style=&quot;white-space:nowrap;&quot;&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; Href=&quot;/Reports/Pages/Default.aspx&quot; style=&quot;text-decoration:none;border-style:none;&quot;&gt;Reports&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td title=&quot;The Search Center displays search results&quot; id=&quot;zz13_GlobalNavn3&quot;&gt;&lt;table class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td style=&quot;white-space:nowrap;&quot;&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; Href=&quot;/SearchCenter/Pages/default.aspx&quot; style=&quot;text-decoration:none;border-style:none;&quot;&gt;Search&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td title=&quot;Site Directory web&quot; id=&quot;zz13_GlobalNavn4&quot;&gt;&lt;table class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td style=&quot;white-space:nowrap;&quot;&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;topNavItem&quot; Href=&quot;/SiteDirectory/Pages/category.aspx&quot; style=&quot;text-decoration:none;border-style:none;&quot;&gt;Sites&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style=&quot;width:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ID' T='GlobalNav' /&gt;&lt;P N='DynamicHoverStyle'&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' T='topNavFlyOutsHover' /&gt;&lt;P N='IsEmpty' T='False' /&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P N='DynamicMenuItemStyle'&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' T='topNavFlyOutsItem' /&gt;&lt;P N='IsEmpty' T='False' /&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P N='DynamicMenuStyle'&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' T='topNavFlyOuts' /&gt;&lt;P N='IsEmpty' T='False' /&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P N='DynamicVerticalOffset' T='-8' /&gt;&lt;P N='MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels' T='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='Orientation' E='0' /&gt;&lt;P N='SkipLinkText' Bound='True' T='Resources:cms,masterpages_skiplinktext' /&gt;&lt;P N='StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='StaticHoverStyle'&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' T='topNavHover' /&gt;&lt;P N='IsEmpty' T='False' /&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P N='StaticMenuItemStyle'&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' T='topNavItem' /&gt;&lt;P N='ItemSpacing' T='0px' /&gt;&lt;P N='IsEmpty' T='False' /&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P N='StaticSelectedStyle'&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' T='topNavSelected' /&gt;&lt;P N='ItemSpacing' T='0px' /&gt;&lt;P N='IsEmpty' T='False' /&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P N='StaticSubMenuIndent' T='0px' /&gt;&lt;P N='DataSourceID' T='SiteMapDataSource1' /&gt;&lt;P N='ControlStyle'&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' ID='1' T='topNav' /&gt;&lt;P N='Font' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='IsEmpty' T='False' /&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P N='CssClass' R='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='Font' R='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='3' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='4' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;" __designer:Templates="&lt;Group Name=&quot;Item Templates&quot;&gt;&lt;Template Name=&quot;StaticItemTemplate&quot; Flags=&quot;D&quot; Content=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;Template Name=&quot;DynamicItemTemplate&quot; Flags=&quot;D&quot; Content=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Group&gt;">
                                    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="topNavItem" ItemSpacing="0"/>
                                    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="topNavSelected" ItemSpacing="0"/>
                                    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="topNavHover"/>
                                    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="topNavFlyOuts" />
                                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="topNavFlyOutsItem" />
                                    <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="topNavFlyOutsHover"/>
                                </SharePoint:AspMenu>
                                <PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDataSource1" Runat="server"
                                    SiteMapProvider="CombinedNavSiteMapProvider" EnableViewState="true"
                                    StartFromCurrentNode="true" StartingNodeOffset="0" ShowStartingNode="false"
                                    TreatStartingNodeAsCurrent="true" TrimNonCurrentTypes="Heading" __designer:Preview="&lt;table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 style=&quot;font:messagebox;color:buttontext;background-color:buttonface;border: solid 1px;border-top-color:buttonhighlight;border-left-color:buttonhighlight;border-bottom-color:buttonshadow;border-right-color:buttonshadow&quot;&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td nowrap&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:bold&quot;&gt;PortalSiteMapDataSource&lt;/span&gt; - siteMapDataSource1&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;/table&gt;" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='ID' T='siteMapDataSource1' /&gt;&lt;P N='SiteMapProvider' T='CombinedNavSiteMapProvider' /&gt;&lt;P N='StartFromCurrentNode' T='True' /&gt;&lt;P N='ShowStartingNode' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='TreatStartingNodeAsCurrent' T='True' /&gt;&lt;P N='TrimNonCurrentTypes' E='32' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="search">
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
                                        <SPSWC:SearchBoxEx id="SearchBox" RegisterStyles="false" TextBeforeDropDown="" TextBeforeTextBox="<%$Resources:cms,masterpages_searchbox_label%>" TextBoxWidth="100" GoImageUrl="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Images/Search_Arrow.jpg %>"
                                            GoImageUrlRTL="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Images/Search_Arrow_RTL.jpg %>" UseSiteDefaults="true" DropDownMode = "HideScopeDD" SuppressWebPartChrome="true" runat="server" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{7DECDCCA-FDA0-4739-8F0E-7B8DE48F0E0D}" __Preview="&lt;table TOPLEVEL border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
    &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td&gt;&lt;table border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr class=&quot;ms-WPHeader&quot;&gt;
                &lt;td title=&quot;&quot; id=&quot;WebPart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: Don't put files in the _layouts folder by hand, use a solution (.wsp) to do this. That way your deployment will be maintainable and repeatable.

Second, to get you on your way :-D, could you check the permissions on the js file using Windows Explorer. It should have the WSS_WPG and WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG (and WSS_ADMIN_WPG) groups assigned to it, both should have read access. After this, restart IIS (app pool recycle is not enough I believe).

When you copy a file from another location to the sharepoint 12-hive, especially one from outside your own environment (i.e. active directory / network), it will not automatically inherit the needed permissions.

Using a solution would circumvent this problem.

I guess you created the pirate.js file directly in the 12 hive or in a folder on your machine with no strict permissions assigned to it. That file probably has the "Everyone" group with read access assigned to it.